# Verificar que una variable es de tipo int y float

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy estudiando informática y estaba practicando lo que he visto en un curso de Youtube para aprender a programar en Python, tras ver el capítulo de bucles  me propuse a profundizar más en donde se intenta verificar que el usuario sea mayor de edad y por otro lado, intentar verificar que un valor es float para poder calcular su raíz cuadrada con .sqrt, tras ver el ejemplo que se dio en el curso, probé introduciendo valores no numéricos en el input y causando así un ValueError, por ello me propuse a intentar solucionarlos y prevenir cualquier otro tipo de error por diferentes tipos de caracteres o símbolos introducidos.

Habiendo aclarado el contexto, la pregunta sería ¿Cuál es la forma mas optima o eficiente para desarrollar este tipo de código que previene casos inesperados, por ejemplo en esta situación, un dígito o un espacio en un input que se esperaría recibiera una entrada numérica y cuál es la mejor forma de abordarlos o en su defecto, por como algunos dicen "para no volver a inventar la rueda" donde podría tomar la referencia más "profesional" o "correcta"?

**Verificar edad:**

```
edad = input("Introduzca su edad: ")

while not edad.isnumeric() or int(edad) < 18 or int(edad) > 100 or edad == "":
    if not edad.isnumeric():
        print("Ha introducido un valor no válido.")
        edad = input("Introduzca su edad: ")
    elif edad == "":
        print("No deje espacios en este campo.,")
        edad = input("Introduzca su edad: ")
    elif int(edad) < 18:
        print("No puede acceder al sistema por ser menor de edad.")
        edad = input("Introduzca su edad: ")
    elif int(edad) > 100:
        print("Ha introducido una edad no válida.")
        edad = input("Introduzca su edad: ")
    else:
        edad = int(edad)
        pass
```

**Calcular raíz cuadrada de un float (Con límite de intentos):**

```
numero = input("Introduzca un valor númerico: ")
intentos = 0

while numero == str(numero) or int(numero) < 0:
    numero_confirm = None
    intentos += 1

    if intentos == 3:
        print("Ha alcanzado el límite de intentos.")
        exit()

    try:
        numero = numero.replace(',', '.', 1)
        numero_confirm = float(numero)
        if float(numero) > 0:
            numero = numero_confirm
            break
        else:
            print("Ha introducido un valor no válido.")
            numero = input("Introduzca un valor numérico: ")
    except ValueError:
        print("Ha introducido un valor no válido.")
        numero = input("Introduzca un valor numérico: ")

if intentos <= 3:
    solucion = math.sqrt(numero)
    print("La raíz cuadrada de %s es %s" % (numero, solucion))
```

Agradezco sus respuestas o cualquier consejo que me puedan dar y disculpen que me extendiera tanto para algo tan simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El ejemplo que has puesto está bien como práctica de aprendizaje; pero son muchos casos los que hay que comprobar, por lo que el código se complica bastante y se hace propenso a errores. Además tienes varias repeticiones del `input`, lo que complica aún más el mantenimiento (Por ejemplo, si quisieras cambiar el mensaje para pedir el número, lo tendrías que cambiar en varias posiciones).

Otro problema que tendría es que estás usando `str.isnumeric` para comprobar si la edad es numérico. Funciona bien en general, pero este método considera número cualquier dígito numérico que figure así en la norma unicode. Como ejemplo: el carácter `'⅕'`, que expresado en unicode sería `"\N{VULGAR FRACTION ONE FIFTH}"`, se considera número, pero da error al convertirlo en entero:

```
>>> s="\N{VULGAR FRACTION ONE FIFTH}"
>>> s
'⅕'
>>> s.isnumeric()
True
>>> int(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '⅕'
>>>
```

El modo habitual de abordar este problema en python es usar el principio [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) (*"Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission"*- Antes pedir perdón que pedir permiso"). Sin comprobar nada, convierte la entrada en entero. Si falla, es que no era un entero:

```
ok = false
while not ok:
    edad = input("Introduzca su edad: ")

    try:
        edad = int(edad)        
    except:
        print("Ha introducido un valor no válido.")
        continue

    ok = 18 <= edad < 100
    if not ok:
        if edad < 18:
            print("No puede acceder al sistema por ser menor de edad."
        elif edad >= 100:
            print("Ha introducido una edad no válida.")
```

En el segundo ejemplo, ya está aplicando el principio EAFP al convertir a *float* para comprobar si es un número real. Lo que te falta es organizar un poco el código para evitar duplicidades. Algo así:

```
intentos = 0
while intentos < 3:
    numero = input("Introduzca un valor númerico: ")
    intentos += 1

    try:
        numero = numero.replace(',', '.', 1)
        numero = float(numero)
    except ValueError:
        print("Ha introducido un valor no válido.")
        continue

    if numero < 0:
        print("No puede ser un número negativo")
        continue

    solucion = math.sqrt(numero)
    print(f"La raíz cuadrada de {numero} es {solucion}")

else:

    print("Ha alcanzado el límite de intentos.")
```

Pero ya que preguntas por una solución más profesional, lo que hay que procurar es separar mejor el código en varios bloques, cada uno que haga una cosa. Y usar el mecanismo de *excepciones* de python para desacoplarlos. Y si usamos notación de tipos, todavía más claro:

```
class DomainError(Exception):
    pass

def pasa_a_float(entrada: str) -> float:
    try:
        numero = numero.replace(',', '.', 1)
        numero = float(numero)
        return numero
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("No es un número válido")

def calcula_raiz(numero: float) -> float:
    if numero < 0:
        raise DomainError("No puede ser un número negativo")

    return math.sqrt(numero)

intentos = 0
while intentos < 3:
    numero = input("Introduzca un valor númerico: ")
    intentos += 1

    try:
        numero = pasa_a_float(numero)
        solucion = calcula_raiz(numero)
        print(f"La raiz de {numero} es {solucion}")
        break
    except ValueError as err:
        print("ValueError:", err)
        continue
    except DomainError as err:
        print("DomainError:", err)
        continue

else:
    print("Ha alcanzado el límite de intentos.")
```

Usamos dos excepciones, la estándar `ValueError`, y una que hemos creado, `DomainError`. Al estar desacoplado de este modo, se pueden añadir más excepciones para añadir más comprobaciones si fuera necesario.

Comment: Estoy planteando en Meta que todas las preguntas de Python muestren una sugerencia para que los usuarios etiqueten de forma más preciso. ¿Podrías darle un vistazo? [¿Podemos añadir una advertencia en las preguntas con etiqueta \[python*\]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3860/83). Tu opinión sería interesante pues eres de los más reputados en esta etiqueta. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Le echo un vistazo y te digo.

Comment: ¡Gracias Chema!

Answer (score 0):

puedes validar asi:
con la funcion `type()` que retorna el tipo de un elemento ejemplo:

```
def es(n):
    if(type(n)==float):
        print("es un flotante")
    if(type(n)==int):
        print("es un entero")
    if(type(n)==str):
        print("es un string")
    if(type(n)== list):
        print("es una lista")
    if(type(n)== dict):
        print("es un diccionario")

es(1.2)
es(1)
es("hola")
es([1,2,3])
es({"numero":1})
```